# Pandas date range with month freqency

Tags: python, pandas, date-range

I would like to generate date range based on any two dates. For example:

```
start_date = "2021-01-15"
end_date = "2021-04-15"
pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq="M")
```

This results in `DatetimeIndex(['2021-01-31', '2021-02-28', '2021-03-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')`.

I would like to update this to get all months including those present in `start_date` and `end_date`. Therefore, I would like to get something like `DatetimeIndex(['2021-01-31', '2021-02-28', '2021-03-31', '2021-04-30'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')` (note `'2021-04-30'` since April is present in `end_date`).

I know there are other frequency options (e.g. [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases)), I can try `freq="MS"` (month starts) which will include the last month (April) but the first one (Jan) will be missing.

I understand that `pd.date_range` always care about days, it makes sense, but since this is not important in my case (I do not care about days, only about months, does not matter whether output will be like `2021-01-01` or `2021-01-31` or even e.g. `2021-01-11`), I'm wondering whether there is any simple solution that could work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`period_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.period_range.html) if working only with months:

```
per = pd.period_range(start_date, end_date, freq="M")
print (per)
PeriodIndex(['2021-01', '2021-02', '2021-03', '2021-04'], dtype='period[M]', freq='M')
```

And for convert to datetimes is possible use [`PeriodIndex.to_timestamp`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.PeriodIndex.to_timestamp.html) with [`DatetimeIndex.normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.normalize.html):

```
print (per.to_timestamp(how='end').normalize())
DatetimeIndex(['2021-01-31', '2021-02-28', '2021-03-31', '2021-04-30'],
               dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```